# How do I use Wget to download all images into a single folder, from a URL?

Tags: wget

I am using wget to download all images from a website and it works fine but it stores the original hierarchy of the site with all the subfolders and so the images are dotted around. Is there a way so that it will just download all the images into a single folder? The syntax I'm using at the moment is:

```
wget -r -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.somedomain.com
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Try this:

```
wget -nd -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.somedomain.com
```

Here is some more information:

`-nd` prevents the creation of a directory hierarchy (i.e. [no directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options)).

`-r` enables recursive retrieval. See [Recursive Download](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download) for more information.

`-P` sets the directory prefix where all files and directories are saved to.

`-A` sets a whitelist for retrieving only certain file types. Strings and patterns are accepted, and both can be used in a comma separated list (as seen above). See [Types of Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files) for more information.

Comment: This didn't actually work for me. My save location was "." and it copied the whole site hierarchy there.

Comment: @ButtleButkus It sounds like you need mess around a bit more with the accept `-A` option, see the Wget documentation about [types of files](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files). Also, if you're downloading to the current directory, you can remove the directory prefix `-P` option. If you're downloading a single file type, such as only jpg's, use something like `wget -r -A.jpg http://www.domain.com`. Look at the [advanced examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Advanced-Usage) that the Wget documentation provides.

Comment: Adding    `-nd`   to the above makes it work. You can also specify multiple -A flags such as `-A "*foo*" -A "*bar*"`

Comment: Don't forget to use `--level=inf` or `--level=9999999999` because `wget` is likely to sabotage the job due to default maximum recursion depth level of `5`.

Comment: this is a useful answer, but I think it does not handle duplicate file names when directories get squashed.  would there be a way to save files as -1.jpg and -2.jpg and so forth?  here they get downloaded as .jpg.1, and then deleted because that's not part of the whitelist.

Answer (score 134):

```
wget -nd -r -l 2 -A jpg,jpeg,png,gif http://t.co
```

- `-nd`: no directories (save all files to the current directory; `-P directory` changes the target directory)
- `-r -l 2`: recursive level 2
- `-A`: accepted extensions

```
wget -nd -H -p -A jpg,jpeg,png,gif -e robots=off example.tumblr.com/page/{1..2}
```

- `-H`: span hosts (wget doesn't download files from different domains or subdomains by default)
- `-p`: page requisites (includes resources like images on each page)
- `-e robots=off`: execute command `robotos=off` as if it was part of `.wgetrc` file. This turns off the robot exclusion which means you ignore robots.txt and the robot meta tags (you should know the implications this comes with, take care).

---

Example: Get all `.jpg` files from an exemplary directory listing:

```
$ wget -nd -r -l 1 -A jpg http://example.com/listing/
```

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a shellscript that solves this problem for multiple websites: https://github.com/eduardschaeli/wget-image-scraper

(Scrapes images from a list of urls with wget)

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```
wget -nd -r -P /save/location/ -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.domain.com
```

and wait until it deletes all extra information

Comment: It is not working for me.`wget -nd -r -P /Users/duraiamuthan/Downloads/images/ -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.forbes.com/profile/mark-zuckerberg/`

Answer (score 5):

According to the man page the -P flag is:

> -P prefix
>        --directory-prefix=prefix
>            Set directory prefix to prefix.  The directory prefix is the
>            directory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved
>            to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree.  The default is . (the
>            current directory).

This mean that it only specifies the destination but where to save the directory tree. **It does not flatten the tree into just one directory**. As mentioned before the -nd flag actually does that.

@Jon in the future it would be beneficial to describe what the flag does so we understand how something works.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions are perfect to download the images and if it is enough for you to save all the files in the directory you are using.
But if you want to save all the images in a specified directory without reproducing the entire hierarchical tree of the site, try to add "cut-dirs" to the line proposed by Jon.

```
wget -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.boia.de --cut-dirs=1 --cut-dirs=2 --cut-dirs=3
```

in this case cut-dirs will prevent wget from creating sub-directories until the 3th level of depth in the website hierarchical tree, saving all the files in the directory you specified.You can add more 'cut-dirs' with higher numbers if you are dealing with sites with a deep structure.

Answer (score -12):

wget utility retrieves files from World Wide Web (WWW) using widely used protocols like HTTP, HTTPS and FTP. Wget utility is freely available package and license is under GNU GPL License. This utility can be install any Unix-like Operating system including Windows and MAC OS. It’s a non-interactive command line tool. Main feature of Wget is it’s robustness. It’s designed in such way so that it works in slow or unstable network connections. Wget automatically start download where it was left off in case of network problem. Also downloads file recursively. It’ll keep trying until file has be retrieved completely.

Install wget in linux machine
sudo apt-get install wget

Create a folder where you want to download files .
sudo mkdir myimages
cd myimages

Right click on the webpage and for example if you want image location right click on image and copy image location. If there are multiple images then follow the below:

If there are 20 images to download from web all at once, range starts from 0 to 19.

wget http://joindiaspora.com/img{0..19}.jpg

Comment: Your answer explains what wget is and how to use it to download sequentially-numbered images...neither are related to the original question.