# How do I pull image links from a website and download them using wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I really want to download images from a website, but I don't know a lot of wget to do so. They host the images on a seperate website, how I do pull the image link from the website using cat or something, so I could use wget to download them all. All I know is the wget part. Example would be Reddit.com

```
  wget -i download-file-list.txt
```

Comment: You can't use only wget. You're going to have to write a shell script that uses pipes and regex.

Comment: This has how to download a whole website with wget, which will include the images: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
wget -r -l 1 -A jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp -nd -H http://reddit.com/some/path
```

It will recurse 1 level deep starting from the page `http://reddit.com/some/path`, and it will not create a directory structure (if you want directories, remove the `-nd`), and it will only download files ending in "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", or "bmp". And it will span hosts.

Comment: The only thing is, the images are hosted a different site. It's a list of tons of urls to images.

Comment: @user1560474 then you want `-H` to span hosts

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `perl` module `WWW::Mechanize`. The following dumps all links to `stdout`:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("URL");
$mech->dump_links(undef, 'absolute' => 1);
```

Replace `URL` with the actual url you want.

Comment: nice method. However, can you change this so that it will take one link at a time from a text file ?