# What is wget and how to get images from a public directory ?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, shell, wget

What is wget and how to get images from a public directory in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A description from [GNU Wget page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

> GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP,
>   HTTPS and FTP, the most widely-used Internet protocols. It is a
>   non-interactive commandline tool, so it may easily be called from
>   scripts, cron jobs, terminals without X-Windows support, etc.

And here is [link for Windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

The question [How do I use Wget to download all Images into a single Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder) describes how to download all images from the given location.

Comment: thanks! i downloaded it but if i click wget.exe, an command line pops up for a split second and its gone :( i guess theres something broken on my computer..

Comment: wget is intended to be run from command line prompt. Click Start->Run, type in `cmd` and press `Enter` to open command line prompt. Then go to directory, where downloaded `wget.exe` is (`cd path\to\my\wget\directory`), and run wget by typing `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

Wget is a command line tool which helps one to retrieve files over the internet. Since it works via command line you can use it non interactively and automate the download process. Wget usually downloads whatever is pointed by the url passed by the user. For instance if one enters the following command
    wget http://www.google.com

Then a html file (index.html) containing the source code of the google homepage will be downloaded to the directory from which you ran the command.