# Automating multiple image download

Tags: image, download

How to automate downloading multiple images from a website? additionally I have a bunch of image URL links . would it be possible to input these image URL links so that i can automate the downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use firefox, have a look for this add-on
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/

Comment: Thanks . i am able to download all the images in one tab or multiple tabs but would it be possible for me to give a bunch of URL's as input and download only those URL's ?

Comment: Use http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ for it! you find the perfect example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder  if you are on windows have a look: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm (and remember to check the question as answered, if it is!)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i tried a bit of this and that and download visualwget where i could specify multiple URL for image downloads ..