# how do i use wget to download all images from the domain

Tags: cmd, wget, image

Hello I would like to download all the pictures from the www.demotywatory.pl website.
I have seen other subject with accepted answer but this does not work for me at all.
The answer was:

```
wget -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.domain.com
```

So i tried that with several websites and alway got that: It looks like it tried only save the one file
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing this:
wget -r -A.jpg http://www.demotywatory.pl

It will download all .jpg files from given URL.

Comment: but I would like to get it from the whole service, like from every url looking like www.demotywatory.pl/*******ANYSIGNS*****

Comment: that's level option in wget, I mean --level option. See this http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html and find --level parameter details

Comment: You can set depth level to 3 or 4, so it will download images linked in inner htmls

Comment: Can I set the minumum resolution or size of the file?

Comment: yes, it's set via --size<min:max>, you can set min or max, read the manual help of wget