# Unable to extract image from website

Tags: python, html, urllib

I am trying to extract an image from the website using python :

relevant command :

```
import urllib
imagelink =  'http://searchpan.in/hacked_captcha.php?450535633'
urllib.urlretrieve(imagelink, "image.jpg")
```

using Firefox to view image shows the following.

[image]

Comment: Only change you need to do is use `.png` instead od `.jpg` , please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is png , all you nedd to do is save it as '.png'

Here is the code

```
import urllib
imagelink =  'http://searchpan.in/hacked_captcha.php?450535633'
urllib.urlretrieve(imagelink, "image.png")
```

Comment: @shrey please check this and accept if it helps you

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following on Python 3. You need to first do a GET request which of-course is abstracted and retrieve the content, writing it to the given filename.

```
import urllib.request

imagelink =  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2F9o.png'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imagelink, './sample.png')
```

**Reference** https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this on one line?

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://searchpan.in/hacked_captcha.php?450535633", "image..jpg")
```

Comment: This wont help as he is `python2.7` and the image is `.png`

Answer (score -1):

there must be .jpg or whatever extension for img the website is using u have to give the full url with extension

[Extract and Download Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408307/how-to-extract-and-download-all-images-from-a-website-using-beautifulsoup)

Go to this link It may be helpfull.

Best of luck...