# Python3 Download Image from an Webpage

Tags: html, python-3.x, image, web-scraping, download

how can I download the image from this URL: https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/
I know it hasn't some image-url but I hope to get some images from there.

My idea is to write a code to get more images from this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate: [Loop through webpages and download all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599798/loop-through-webpages-and-download-all-images)

**Python 2**

Using urllib.urlretrieve

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.gunnerkrigg.com//comics/00000001.jpg", "00000001.jpg")
```

**Python 3**

Using urllib.request.urlretrieve (part of Python 3's legacy interface, works exactly the same)

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.gunnerkrigg.com//comics/00000001.jpg", "00000001.jpg")
```

Comment: When I use this example than I get following Error Message: "Forbidden"

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/ ", "00000001.jpg")

Comment: I mean when I use this code for this URL 'thispersondoesnotexist.com