# Troubble with wget and external images

Tags: command-line, wget

I am trying to download all the images displayed on this website and save them onto my desktop.
The images are being displayed by a php script that scopes our facebook page of the last five days. My hope is when running this script will go onto this webpage and save all the images onto our desktop. 
So far, I have this code, but it is not saving any images, just the webpage itself.

```
wget -r -P /Users/tcokimac/Desktop/ "http://awakenstudios.net/scripts/fbalbumdw/?pageid=117948231563146&useToken=&name=sonrise+adult+teen+challenge&daysgoback=5&makehtmlOnly=2"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and download all images from a website using beautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408307/how-to-extract-and-download-all-images-from-a-website-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: No. The images are still being downloaded to "/Users/tcokimac/" not "/Users/tcokimac/Desktop/"