# How to download all images from a website using wget?

Tags: image, wget, forum

Here is an example of my command:

```
wget -r -l 0 -np -t 1 -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png -nd --connect-timeout=10 -P ~/support --load-cookies cookies.txt "http://support.proboards.com/" -e robots=off
```

[Based on the input here](http://www.krazyworks.com/wget-examples-and-scripts/)

But nothing really gets downloaded, no recursive crawling, it takes just a few seconds to complete.  I am trying to backup all images from a forum, is the forum structure causing issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder/21089847#comment33143483_21089847

Answer (score 19):

```
wget -r -P /download/location -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png http://www.site.here
```

works like a charm

Comment: in my case this downloads `robots.txt` file only

Comment: in case you only get robots.txt then you can append '-e robots=off --wait 1 http://www.site.here
' to your wget command. This will overwrite the robots.txt file and fetch you the content you are looking for. Eg:

wget -r -P /download/location -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png -e robots=off --wait 1 http://www.site.here

Comment: Watch out using the recursive `-r` tag. This can cause all sorts of external files to be downloaded too.

Answer (score 0):

Download image file with another name.
Here I provide the wget.zip file name as shown below.

```
# wget -O wget.zip http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.5.3.tar.gz
--2012-10-02 11:55:54--  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.5.3.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.gnu.org... 208.118.235.20, 2001:4830:134:3::b
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org|208.118.235.20|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 446966 (436K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: wget.zip
100%[===================================================================================>] 446,966     60.0K/s   in 7.5s
2012-10-02 11:56:02 (58.5 KB/s) - wget.zip
```