# Batch script for wget

Tags: windows, batch-file, wget

I need to do a script for download images resursive, How can i do it. I am on a Windows.

I want something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++) {
   wget "http://download/img" + i + ".png
}
```

How can i do this with a Windows Batch script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder

Comment: i dont want to download all the images, i only need to download images on a range

Comment: If you have any pattern, ‘reject-regex = urlregex’ or ‘accept-regex = urlregex’ can be used like in http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows equivalent to that sort of `for` loop is `for /L`.  Syntax is

```js
for /L %%I in (start,step,finish) do (stuff)
```

See `help for` in a console window for more info.  Also, Windows batch variables are evaluated inline.  No need to break out of your quotes.

```js
for /L %%I in (0,1,100) do (
    wget "http://download/img%%I.png"
)
```

... will download img0.png through img100.png with no numeric padding.

If the numbers are zero padded, there's an added element to consider -- delayed expansion.  Within a `for` loop, variables are evaluated before the `for` loop loops.  Delaying expansion causes the variables to wait until each iteration to be evaluated.  So, zero padding then taking the right-most 3 characters requires something like this:

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%I in (0,1,100) do (
    set "idx=00%%I"
    wget "http://download/img!idx:~-3!.png"
)
```

... which will download img000.png through img100.png.

Answer (score 0):

There are some parameters that can be used with wget including a recursive mode and also extension filter.

Please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder)