# Download and save image from a website using wget

Tags: command-line, windows-7, wget

How do I download and save the particular image from the following web page using `wget`.

http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?SceneView&ImageID=509617654

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4602153/1247080)

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget" -r -P "C:\temp\" -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png "http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?SceneView&ImageID=509617654"
```

But the image did not download and save. I am using Windows 7. I guess I am not getting the image since the web page is not a proper html page (no html or asp etc extension). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. A file extension is not required for URLs containing HTML (e.g. http://google.com/).

By inspecting the HTML source (ignoring that the page has invalid HTML (`<script>` tag in between `<head>` and `<body>`)), we can see it's using JavaScript to alter the image's `src` attribute on page load (why, who knows...) to `/GetBinary.aspx?Scene&ImageID=509617654&CaseID=&Version=` (relative to the HTML page).

As **`wget` can't execute JS**, this will never work (like this).

However the [actual image URL](http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx/GetBinary.aspx?Scene&ImageID=509617654&CaseID=&Version=) does return a JPEG image, but you'll have to rename it, as, also, the web server (IIS) is misconfigured, as for that URL it returns a header:

```
Content-Type: E:\Sites\NASS\CDS\/img/jpg
```

which is invalid, and causes file association problems when downloading in most browsers / clients.

To prove it's there, you can try downloading it directly with `wget`:

```
wget "http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx/GetBinary.aspx?Scene&ImageID=509617654&CaseID=&Version=" -O image.jpg
```