# How get all images in a folder from link?

Tags: image, hyperlink, ftp, get

I want to know how to download all the images in a folder by knowing the link of the folder but not the links of images.

I wonder if there is a software or an extension to do that.

Comment: Use the tool **wget** to download a folders contents.

Comment: Also please read [stackoverflow]'s [faq] - this question isn't a good fit. Good luck!

Comment: I can not use wget as there is no page with images on a page.

I try to get all the images in a folder without having to page images appear.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Have you tried wget? Closing this question as duplicate, the answer is here mate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder