# Download multiple images (PNG) at once using WGET

Tags: javascript, python, http, https, wget

I am trying to download all the images (in both sizes) on http://emojipedia.org/apple/ . I am on Mac using wget, and have tried commands such as

wget -nd -np -r -P app/emojis -A.png

and it has not worked for me. It downloads indexes, and often does not download anything at all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder

Answer (score 0):

The images are in an external host `<img src="http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/87/f7/87f7253beff07c22cb264c91d5f40eda.png" />`

You need the -H parameter. It enables downloading of linked resources that are hosted at different hosts/domains.

Ex.

`wget -nd -r -H -P app/emojis -A png http://emojipedia.org/apple/`

Comment: This seems to begin working (downloading the pngs) but just stops and instead begins downloading robots.txt files. I am seeing this in the finder, is it possible I am not letting it run long enough? I tried multiple times and let it run over 30 minutes. I only need the pngs on this specific site. Please advise, thank you.