# How to extract image urls using bash?

Tags: bash, download

I would like to extract the image URL from page's html code using bash commands and then download all images from that page. I am not sure whether it is possible, as sometimes they ae stored in folders which I wouldn't have access to.
But is it possible to download them from the source code?

I have written this so far:

````
wget -O plik.txt $1 
grep *.jpg plik.txt > wget
grep *.png plik.txt > wget
grep *.gif plik.txt > wget
rm plik.txt```
````

Comment: You cannot parse HTML code from a Bash script. To parse any markup language, you need specific parsers (same for HTML, XML, SGML, JSON, YAML, INI and even CSV require specific parsers).

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/questions/1219455/how-to-download-all-images-from-a-website-using-wget or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder-from-a-url

Answer (score 2):

Using lynx (a text web browser) in non-interactive mode, and GNU `xargs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

lynx -dump -listonly -image_links -nonumbers "$1" |
grep -Ei '\.(jpg|png|gif)$' |
tr '\n' '\000' |
xargs -0 -- wget --no-verbose --
```

- This will start downloading matching image URLs in the web page URL given in `$1`, straight away.
- It will include both images in the page, and images that are linked. Removing `-image_links` will skip images on the page.
- You can add/remove whichever extensions you want to download, following the pattern I provided for `.jpg`, `.png`, and `.gif`. (`grep -i` is case insensitive).
- The reason for using null delimiters (via `tr`) is to use `xargs -0`, which will avoid problems with URLs which contain a single quote/apostrophe (`'`).
- The `--no-verbose` flag for wget just simplifies the log output. I find it easier to read if downloading a large list of files.
- Note that regular GNU wget will handle any duplicate filenames, by appending a number (`foo.jpg.1` etc). However, busybox wget for example just exits if a filename exists, abandoning further downloads.
- You can also modify the `xargs` to just print a list of the files to be downloaded, so you can review it first: `xargs -0 -- sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' _`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Just note that if you get paths with query parameters like `.../image.jpg?size=medium` you should remove the `$` from the `grep` portion